# Loading Code from Tab only when tab is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

I have a series of tabs. I understand that all tabs load once the page is loaded. I have one tab however which I would like to be an exception to this. It contains a widget that I am loading which I would only like to load once the use clicks that specific tab.

```
 <div class="tabbable tabbable-custom">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a id="nav-tabs-2" data-toggle="tab" href="#info">Details</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#live">Live View</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#local">Local Storage</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

and then this is my tab

```
    <div id="local" class="tab-pane">
    <div evercam="localstorage"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.evercam.io/js/localstorage/0.0.1/hikvision.local.storage.mini.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click','show.bs.tab', function() {
      if ($(this).attr('href') == '#local' && !LocalStorage.isLoaded()) {
        // Set Evercam Camera ID
        LocalStorage.options.cameraId = '<%= @camera['id'] %>';

        // OR //
        // Using api_id and api_key
        LocalStorage.options.api_id = '<%= current_user.api_id -%>';
        LocalStorage.options.api_key = '<%= current_user.api_key -%>';

        // Finally Load the widget
        LocalStorage.Load();
      }
    })


    </script>
    </div><!--TAB PANE -->
```

This loads the widget when the user clicks the tab. The problem I have is if the user leaves the tab and then goes back to it - it reloads the widget and I have two instances of the widget! Is there any way to have it so that it only loads once?

Comment: your binding event is wrong. `$(selector).on('click','show.bs.tab', function(){//let do awesomething here });`

Comment: Hi thanks Jh Kaiz, I have updated my code up above. I have tried with and without this bit in between `if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#local') {//}` but neither is working. Can you see what I have wrong?

Comment: could you provide your HTML code? Just `<container><tab1/> <tab2/></container>` only, I need to provide JS solution for you dude :). in this case, I think what you expect is  `if ($(this).attr('href') == '#local') { // do something you want;}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your code structure, but it seems like a case where you could do the following:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click','show.bs.tab', function(e) {
 if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#local' && !LocalStorage.isLoaded()) {
 // Set Evercam Camera ID
 LocalStorage.options.cameraId = '<%= @camera['id'] %>';

 // OR //
 // Using api_id and api_key
 LocalStorage.options.api_id = '<%= current_user.api_id -%>';
 LocalStorage.options.api_key = '<%= current_user.api_key -%>';

 // Finally Load the widget
 LocalStorage.Load();
 }
});
```

So it'll consider both, if the right tab is clicked AND if the widget is loaded

**UPDATE**

Ok, got a little bit mistaken up there.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
   // Check if the clicked tab is the right one
   // Also check if the widget is loaded
   if ($(this).attr('href') == '#local' && !LocalStorage.isLoaded()) {
     // Set Evercam Camera ID
     LocalStorage.options.cameraId = '<%= @camera['id'] %>';

     // OR //
     // Using api_id and api_key
     LocalStorage.options.api_id = '<%= current_user.api_id -%>';
     LocalStorage.options.api_key = '<%= current_user.api_key -%>';

     // Finally Load the widget
     LocalStorage.Load();
  }
 });
```

I have no idea how your `LocalStorage` object works, is it a thrid party library? Is it your own? If the former, they probably have a method to check if there's a running instance. If the latter, you could do just

```
LocalStorage.prototype.isLoaded = function() {
  //Here you write code to check if there is a running instance of the widget loaded
  return this.widget !== undefined
}
```

Or you could simply write the `Load` function in a way to allow only one instance to be running

(Remove the `'show.bs.modal'` reference. This is an event fired by bootstrap when you show the tab, it has nothing to do with the click http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs )

Comment: put e in `function()` dude, if not  `e is undefined` error will be thrown :D.

Comment: need a little modified more, I think we should use `$(this).attr('href')` than `$(e.target).attr('href')`. It'll be wrong if inside `.show.bs.tab` has a span or something, in this case the `$(e.target) === $('.show.bs.tab span')` (in this case, we don't need `function(e)` anymore, sorry).

Comment: Wouldn't `this` be a span too in this case, @JhKaiz ?

Comment: `this` in this case is the `.show.bs.tab` - what you trigger event click on, but `e.target` return the `<element/>` that you click on it. If I create a dynamic tab with icon, look like `<a class="show bs tab" href="#local"><span class="tab-name">Local</span><i class="tab-icon-local"></i></a>`, `e.target` maybe return `<span/>` or `<i/>`

Comment: Definitely hahahaha But I don't think creating a tag with classes that match exactly the name of the bootstrap event makes much sense LOL But I got your point. What I meant was: When `e.target` refers to the span, wouldn't `this` also refer to the span?

Comment: Ah ok, got it... Fair enough\

Comment: Hi guys really appreciate all the help but just got a little lost in the conversation! Is what I have in my edit above right? My widget isn't loading for me probably haven't followed you right!

Comment: check this fiddle, you'll got what I want to tell you guys : http://jsfiddle.net/u6k2s5ky @AlexandreWiechersVaz

Comment: Updated the answer, @Ciarán . Tried to give you an idea of how to achieve what you wanted. It'd be good to have an idea of how your LocalStorage object is structured

Answer (score 0):

check this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/u6k2s5ky/1/), I hope it will end this question :).

Fix the localStorage problem : [`Fiddle2`](http://jsfiddle.net/u6k2s5ky/3/)

Comment: Hi Jh Kaiz, thanks for creating this. This loads the code when the tab is clicked but I still have the issue that if I navigate to a different tab and back it causes the javascript to load again and so I end up with two instances of the widget I am loading

Comment: check my update if it match your idea @Ciarán. localStorage has 3 function : `setItem(), removeItem(), getItem()`